# Find a tangent and normal equation for a function: $u=\sin(x) \ln(1+2y^2)$ at $M=[\pi/2;-1]$

Tags: real-analysis

So, I need to find tangent equation and normal equation for a function given as: $u=\sin(x) \cdot\ln(1+2y^2), M= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\pi}{2} \\ -1\end{bmatrix}$. Here is my take on it, but I assume that I made a mistake somewhere, because the derivatives are not whole numbers and also because a value of derivative after $x$ is zero and hence the normal equation is not complete.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u\left(\frac\pi2,-1\right)=\log(3)$ and since$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\left(\frac\pi2,-1\right)=0\text{ and }\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\left(\frac\pi2,-1\right)=-\frac43,$$the tangent plane at $\left(\frac\pi2,-1\right)$ is the plane$$\left\{\left(\frac\pi2,-1,\log(3)\right)+\alpha(1,0,0)+\beta\left(0,1,-\frac43\right)\,\middle|\,\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$Since$$(1,0,0)\times\left(0,1,-\frac43\right)=\left(0,\frac43,1\right),$$the normal line to the surfact at the point that you are interested in is$$\left\{\left(\frac\pi2,-1,\log(3)\right)+\gamma\left(0,\frac43,1\right)\,\middle|\,\gamma\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$

Here's a image of your surface, together with the tangent plane and the normal line:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your notation. Why is $f_y(x_0;y_0)=-\frac{4}{3}$ if at $y_0=-1 \ \ ln(1+2y^2)=ln(3).$ Then $f_y(x_0;y_0)=-\frac{4}{ln(3)}.$ How would you write the expression you have written in curly brackets as an equation not as vectors multiplied by some alpha and beta? You see that $f_x(x_0;y_0)=0$ then how do I write the normal equation in the way shown in my original post? The most I don't get how can you have $\frac{4}{3}$ instead of $\frac{4}{ln(3)}$.

Comment: If $f(x,y)=\sin(x)\log(1+2y^2)$, then$$f_y(x,y)=\frac{4\sin(x)y}{1+2y^2}$$and therefore $f_y\left(\frac\pi2,-1\right)=-\frac43$.

Comment: Ok, my error. I will update the original post.

Comment: I updated original post, could you check whether my solution is correct? What about the normal equation? I wrote it without one ratio because you cannot divide by 0.

Comment: If you are saying that the tangent plane is the plane $z-\log(3)=-\frac43(y+1)$, then you are right. That is the same plane that I got. But I did not understand what is that you got when you tried to compute the normal line.